# AllJoyn Notification Acknowledgement Android

Tags: android, alljoyn

I want to use the AllJoyn Notification SDK for Android to send and receive notifications across all Android devices connected to a single Wi-Fi router. Is there any way through which I can confirm that my sent notification has been received on all the devices?